# I am getting error in Routing in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

**Error says  - >**

> ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(29,14): error TS2322: Type '{
>   path: string; component: string; }[]' is not assignable to type
>   'Route[]'.   Type '{ path: string; component: string; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'Route'.
>       Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type'.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { SliderComponent } from './slider/slider.component';
import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form/signup-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routes: Routes = [

  {path : 'ImgSlider' , component: 'SliderComponent'},
  {path : 'signup'  , component: 'SignupFormComponent'},

];
```

Comment: Just remove the quotes from component. It will be `component: SliderComponent`

Comment: Remove the single quotes from your components in the `routes` config

Answer (score 5):

the error tells you that the arguments of your routes are wrong, since it should be like this

```
export const routes: Routes = [

 {path : 'ImgSlider' , component: SliderComponent},
 {path : 'signup'  , component: SignupFormComponent},
 ];
```

which means components names shouldn't be written as string.

Answer (score 2):

```
{path : 'ImgSlider' , component: 'SliderComponent'},
{path : 'signup'  , component: 'SignupFormComponent'},
```

this is your code tag.

According to angular documentation there is no use of single quote in component of routing file. and you add extra comma at the end of your signup path. if you have declare other path after signup path then you use comma other wise it throws an exception. Here it is the correct way

```
{path : 'ImgSlider' , component: SliderComponent},
{path : 'signup'  , component: SignupFormComponent}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this step by step.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

It will definitely work.

```
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes/heroes.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent } //here you have marked it as string it should be refer to component name
];
```

To the @NgModule.imports array and configure it with the routes in one step by 
calling RouterModule.forRoot()

```
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes on your component 
eg:

```
{path : 'ImgSlider' , component: SliderComponent},
```

Answer (score 1):

First import RouterModule as:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

then add it to the @NgModule.imports array and configure it with the routes by calling RouterModule.forRoot()

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And remove the single quotes on your component as I mentioned below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'ImgSlider', component: SliderComponent}
];
```

It works for me.